# For $U \subseteq \mathbb{H}^{k}$, why is $U \cap \delta\mathbb{H}^{k} = \underbrace{U^{*}}_{\mathbb{R}^{k-1}} \times 0$?

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, manifolds

Here is the full statement I wish to prove:

For $U \subseteq \mathbb{H}^{k}$, why is $U \cap \delta\mathbb{H}^{k} = \underbrace{U^{*}}_{\mathbb{R}^{k-1}} \times 0$? where $U^{*}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{k-1}$ and $U$ in $\mathbb{H}^{k}$.

Here, $\mathbb{H}^{k}$ is defined as $\{ x_{1} \dots x_{k-1}, x_{k}| x_{k} \geq 0\ , x_{i} \in \mathbb{R}\}$

$\delta \mathbb{H}^{k}$ is the  border of the manifold $\mathbb{H}^{k}$. That is $\delta \mathbb{H}^{k} = (\{x_{1} \dots x_{k-1}\} \times 0) $.

This is used as part of a proof in Analysis on Manifolds (on page 207 of the older edition).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you let $U \subset \mathbb{H}^k$ then $U = \{(x_1,...,x_k): x_k \geq 0\}$ where $x_1,...x_k$ are the coordinate functions on $\mathbb{H}^k$ and in the definition of $U$, these coordinate functions are restricted to $U$. The boundary of the upper half plane is $\{(x_1,...,0)\}$ i.e $U \cap \partial \mathbb{H}^k = \{(x_1,...,x_{k-1},x_k=0)\} = U^* \times \{0\}$. Here we let $U^* = \{(x_1,...,x_{k-1})_U\}$ which is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{k-1}$.

Comment: I accepted your answer. Another way to argue for the open-ness of $U^{*}$ is to argue that if $U^{*}$ were not open, then $U$ could not possibly be open in $H^{k}$. The reasoning to prove this is similar to that used to argue that if a set $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, then the sets intersection with $\mathbb{R}$ must be open in $\mathbb{R}$